# Porque estou perdendo os valores dos <input> ao abrir e fechar um <iframe> usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

**Contexto:** tenho uma aplicação, que utiliza [php](/questions/tagged/php)+[html](/questions/tagged/html)+[css](/questions/tagged/css)+[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)(com [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)). Nela eu tenho uma página chamada `principal.php` que contém um iframe: `<iframe src=pedido.php/>` dentro chamando a `pedido.php`, como podemos ver. Dentro da página `pedido.php` eu tenho varios `<input type=text>` e tem um especifico que quero preencher com dados, ao lado dele temos uma `lupa` que ao clicar nela eu executo a seguinte função javascript:

```js
function buscaIndicou(id_elemento){
  var parametros = "?disablebuttons=true";
  var width          = $(window).width()+"px";
  var height         = $(window).height()+"px";
  var $div           = $("<div />", { "class":"overflow-box"}).css({"width":width,"height":height});
  var $close         = $("<div />", {"class":"close"}).click(function(){
    $('.overflow-box').remove();
    $('.modal').remove();
    $('.close').remove();
    if (getCookie("IDPessoaModal") == "")
        alert("Ocorreu um erro ao selecionar a Pessoa, tente novamente.");
    else{
      var id  = getCookie("IDPessoaModal");
      var nm  = getCookie("NMPessoaRel");
      var ele = getCookie("TargetEdit");
      $('#'+ele).val(nm);
      $('#'+ele).attr('data-id',id);
      deleteCookie("BuscaDoPedido");
    }
  });
  $('#pnlContent').append($div);
  var html  = '<div class=modal>'+
              '<iframe width="987" height="426" frameborder="0" scrolling=no src="listapessoa.php'+parametros+'" id="mainFrame">'+
              '</div>';
  $('#pnlContent').html($('#pnlContent').html()+html);
  $('.modal').append($close);
}
```

Esse código abre um `<iframe>` na minha tela com aspecto de modal, aí eu vou lá escolho uma Pessoa na lista, salvo nos cookies que eu uso ali depois no evento do `click()` da `div.close` e depois clico na `div.close` que dá um `.remove()` em tudo que eu criei.

**Problema:** Quando os elementos que eu criei são removidos, e eu volto a ver meu `<input>` e a lupa, as informações são carregadas pra ele corretamente, porém, todos os outros `<input>` que eu havia preenchido, estão vazios.

Porque eles ficaram vazios se eu não recarreguei nem fechei o `<iframe src=pedido.php>` e apenas criei outro `<iframe>` dentro dele depois fechei?

Obs: Tenho certeza que não há problema com código PHP ou HTML, por isso não postei nada deles, porém se vocês insistirem posso tentar criar um exemplo parecido pois o meu código PHP+HTML é de difícil entendimento e é enorme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#pnlContent').html($('#pnlContent').html()+html);
```

Você está sobrescrevendo o seu HTML. Use isso:

```
$('#pnlContent').after(html);
```

Comment: Não acredito, era uma coisa tão simples e eu aqui pensando na teoria da relatividade, kkk